# Opening a file using relative path on Linux in C

Tags: c, linux, file

I'm new to c programming. I have the following directory structure.

```
Project
   |____ dataset
   |        |_____ data.txt
   |
   |____ main.c
```

My code:

```c
FILE *stream = fopen("dataset/data.txt", "r");
```

or

```c
FILE *stream = fopen("./dataset/data.txt", "r");
```

returns this error: **`No such file or directory`**

But when I use the absolute path it works without any error:

```c
FILE *stream = fopen("/home/<user_name>/C/<project_name>/dataset/data.txt", "r");
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: A relative path only works when you're in the correct c*urrent folder*

Comment: What is the current directory when you run the program?  Does the program ever change  directory?  The base position for the relative path is unrelated to the location of the source code; the only thing that matters is the current working directory of the process.

Comment: IOW, try something like: `const char *path = "dataset/data.txt"; if( (stream = fopen(path, "r")) == NULL ){ perror(path); printf("current dir: %s\n", getcwd(NULL, 0); exit(1); }`

Comment: @WilliamPursell I get it now. I was using CLion. The final executable after building is in the `./cmake-build-debug` directory. So i used `../dataset/data.txt` and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Read [path_resolution(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/path_resolution.7.html).

You may want to use [chdir(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chdir.2.html), since [fopen(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html) calls [open(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) and all of them could fail.

When `fopen` fails (or some  [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) fails) use [errno(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html) or [perror(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/perror.3.html).

Be aware of [glob(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/glob.3.html), [getcwd(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getcwd.2.html) and [fnmatch(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fnmatch.3.html).

See also [proc(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html).